# Canno't login to my ubuntu 18.04LTS server after changing files permission

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-cloud-platform, permissions, chown

I had to deal with executing a bash command from a PHP local server on my Ubuntu server from Google Cloud and a few moments after finding the solution I was disconnected from the server and I'm now unable to log back.

The command **I've run to change directory permissions**:
`sudo chown -R www-data /home/my_username`

Needless to say I've fucked up. 
My site is still up but **I can't log in anymore with ssh**
`ssh my_username@server_ip`  -> Error: Permission denied (publickey).
or with Google Cloud.

Do you have any leads before I restart a server from scratch?

Comment: Here is a possible recipe for getting in to a locked out Compute Engine ... https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b

Answer (score 1):

As per Kaybec's shared [documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b):

> The solution is to create a startup script that adds a userid/password
>   pair. If we define this script and then restart our Compute Engine,
>   during the later part of the boot process, the startup script will run
>   which can create our identity which we can then use to login. Once the
>   startup script has completed and the VM instance started, we can then
>   login through the serial port.
>
> Here is walk through of these steps assuming, at the outset, that we
>   are locked out:
>
> 1. We enable serial port login by setting the Compute Engine instance metadata `serial-port-enable to 1`. In Cloud Console there is a checkbox
>      area which makes this simple:
> 2. Next we shutdown the Compute Engine instance.
>
> Once shutdown, we can define our startup script by adding custom
>   metadata with the key of startup-script and the value of:

```
useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
    echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
```

You can also do this on the console, under GCE page of your VM instance where it says to add "Custom metadata"

> 3. Now we restart the Compute Engine. This will cause the startup script
>      to execute which will add our temporary user. When the Compute Engine
>      has started, we will see a button in the Console of the details of our
>      instance.
>
> We have to press the enter key once in the resulting window to cause
>   the login prompt to appear.
>
> We can now enter our userid and password (eg. tempuser / password). We
>   will be logged in as our temporary user. We can now switch to a root
>   user shell using:

```
sudo bash
```

> 4. At this point, we are now in the machine with all the authority we may
>      need. We can perform our investigation and repair. When we are happy
>      that the environment has been fixed, we should shutdown the VM
>      instance and remove the startup script that creates our temporary
>      userid and we should also uncheck the box that enables serial port
>      login.

We should restart the VM one more time and and login with SSH and should explicitly remove our temporary user:

```
deluser tempuser
```